# Memory Error Detection tool

Tags: segmentation-fault, runtime-error, valgrind

I have a game application that does lot of work in terms of CPU processing and Memory access. I have got couple of random crashes and would like to use a tool to fix them. I was thinking of using Valgrind but it slows down the application a lot.
Is there a light-weight tool that can help me detect corrupt memory accesses without slowing down the application by large factor?

Comment: Yes, there is AddressSanitizer.

Comment: We are using gcc/g++ 4.0.2. AddressSanitizer comes with latest version of gcc. wondering if I can build the tool separately ?

Comment: Is there any other tool ?